# MongoDB can't get all the rows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a project using the MEAN stack and inside the Mongo DB  collection I've got a collection called 'services' with the following rows (a small subset):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55af611de2be6d817d000001"), "client" : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002", "collaborators" : null, "date" : ISODate("2015-07-22T09:23:41.917Z"), "latestUpdateDate" : ISODate("2015-07-22T09:23:41.917Z"), "backofficeRequested" : false, "description" : "Uma descrição qq", "wasSeen" : 0, "currentStatusId" : "0", "lastStatusId" : 4, "__v" : 2, "addresses" : [ ], "dates" : [ ], "estimateDuration" : 61, "estimatePrice" : "55", "notes" : [ ], "serviceDate" : ISODate("2015-07-23T10:07:00Z"), "totalPrice" : "600", "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55afa8662c1e98c80d2fd2ff"), "client" : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002", "estimatePrice" : "12", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(720), "description" : "12", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1212-12-12T12:48:45Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : "0", "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55acb6022c1e98d05f2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55afa9f62c1e98370e2fd2ff"), "client" : "55ae68d82c1e98ac782fd303", "estimatePrice" : "12", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(720), "description" : "12", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1212-12-12T12:48:45Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : "1", "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55acb6022c1e98d05f2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "500", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55afaa7e2c1e98bc0d2fd2ff"), "client" : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002", "estimatePrice" : "12", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(720), "description" : "12", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1212-12-12T12:48:45Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : "0", "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55acb6022c1e98d05f2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55afaf582c1e98d80d2fd303"), "client" : "55ae68d82c1e98ac782fd303", "estimatePrice" : "1", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(60), "description" : "1", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1111-11-11T11:47:45Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : "4", "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55ae40772c1e98007a2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55afb8472c1e98370e2fd300"), "client" : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002", "estimatePrice" : "1", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(60), "description" : "1", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1111-11-11T11:47:45Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : NumberLong(2), "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55ae40772c1e98007a2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55aff2dc2c1e98ac112fd2ff"), "client" : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002", "estimatePrice" : "1", "estimateDuration" : NumberLong(720), "description" : "1", "serviceDate" : ISODate("1989-12-12T12:12:00Z"), "lastStatusId" : null, "currentStatusId" : NumberLong(2), "collaborators" : [ { "id" : "55ae40772c1e98007a2fd2ff" } ], "dates" : [ ], "totalPrice" : "", "backofficeRequested" : NumberLong(0), "serviceInvoiced" : "No", "evaluation" : "", "positiveFeatures" : "", "negativeFeatures" : "" }
```

I want to get all the rows belonging to the client with the ID "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002".

It's pretty easy to do in the mongo Shell:

```
db.services.find({"client":"55a8e5fa586f94752a000002"})
```

But I am having a hard time inside Node.js because it either returns no services at all or it ends up returning just one service.

Here's what I'm using right now:

```
(...)

console.log(checkDatas[0]._id);
Service.find().where('client', checkDatas[0]._id)
.exec(function(err, services)
{
    console.log("output: " + services);

(...)
```

And finally, here's the output:

```
**55a8e5fa586f94752a000002**

**output**: { _id: 55aff719af19b58913000001,
  client: 55a8e5fa586f94752a000002,
  __v: 1,
  collaborators: [ { id: '55acb6022c1e98d05f2fd2ff' } ],
  notes: [],
  dates: [],
  addresses: [],
  date: Wed Jul 22 2015 22:03:37 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  latestUpdateDate: Wed Jul 22 2015 22:03:37 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  backofficeRequested: false,
  totalPrice: null,
  estimatePrice: null,
  estimateDuration: null,
  description: '',
  serviceDate: null,
  wasSeen: 0,
  currentStatusId: 3,
  lastStatusId: 1 }
```

It's as if I were using findOne but I'm not.

On top of that, yesterday I had a .sort() method also in that query and things worked fine after commenting it but today the problem's back.

Do MongoDB / Node have some sort of caching system I'm not aware of?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Running

```
Service.find({'client': checkDatas[0]._id})
```

yields the same result

Comment: That is strange. What versions of Node/Mongo are you using? Also what client are you using? Out of curiosity does `Service.find({client: checkDatas[0]._id})` produce the same results?

Comment: I'm using node v0.13.0-pre, MongoDB 2.6.10 and MongoDB Shell 3.0.3. Please see the edit.

Comment: can you post your schema definition please?

Comment: Odds are on the "client" is defined as `ObjectId` in the shema, and that there is a stray value in the collection that is an `ObjectId` and not a string. Notably the "match" is missing from the sample provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing `ObjectId`'s and strings, which are two different things.

Your Mongoose query is looking for an `ObjectId`:

```
Service.find().where('client', checkDatas[0]._id)
```

Quick tip: you can distinguish both types in the output:

```
// ObjectId, because it doesn't have quotes around it
client: 55a8e5fa586f94752a000002
// String
collaborators: [ { id: '55acb6022c1e98d05f2fd2ff' } ]
```

Your MongoDB shell query is looking for a string:

```
db.services.find({"client":"55a8e5fa586f94752a000002"})
```

The subset you're posting shows only strings, but I think that your database may actually contain both types. You can check and see if this works better:

```
Service.find().or([
  { client : checkDatas[0]._id },
  { client : String(checkDatas[0]._id) }
])...
```

Obviously this isn't ideal, you should consider normalizing your database if both types are mixed.

**EDIT**: the `or` query probably won't work when using Mongoose, since it will cast both clauses to the type defined in the schema. You can still check from the Mongo shell:

```
db.services.find({ $or : [
 { client : "55a8e5fa586f94752a000002" },
 { client : ObjectId("55a8e5fa586f94752a000002") }
]})
```

Comment: That really should not matter as long as the "client" field is defined as `String`. It should just stringify ie. `.toString()`. Does for me anyway. However I won't rule out that the schema is defined incorrectly as `ObjectId`

Comment: @BlakesSeven true, but if the database contains both types (perhaps the schema changed at some point) you either get one or the other.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I said above. One stray `ObjectId` and the schema defined that way would produce the result. But if it's a "String" in schema definition then the result would be reversed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I now wonder if the `or` query would have any effect, because Mongoose will probably cast both of the clauses to the type in the schema...

Comment: Nope. If you have a Schema type of `ObjectId` then any "valid" string will be cast to that type. If you have a schema type of `String` then "any" object will have it's `.toString()` method called and the content will be saved as that result. Same applies to query arguments. Try it yourself :)

Comment: Perfect! It really was the schema... Sorry for the noobness, I just landed on this legacy project and I'm still getting to know MongoDB